# What're the key codes for "Alt+Q Alt+Q"?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I want to create a script that triggers when pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> twice while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but couldn't figure out what're the correct key codes for that, could someone please shed some light?

P.S. I want to bind this shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, which I assigned [Sogou IME](https://pinyin.sogou.com/) to turn on the Chinese input mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

> **In conclusion, even if I do all kinds of hacks and get the script working as intended, it's likely to break in the future, which is really not worth the trouble.**

---

After hours of experimenting, the current conclusion is [Sogou IME](https://pinyin.sogou.com/) which uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> won't trigger the bound action i.e. switching to the Chinese input mode if it was sent by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[Any Other Key]</kbd>, it *can* be triggered if it was sent by other shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which is really unfortunate.

And the weirdest thing is the following code works:

```
^c::Send !q
!q::Send ^{F12}
```

And to rule out the potential [extra simulated keystrokes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by default)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) effect, the following code also works:

```
^!q::Send ^{F12}
```

But the following **doesn't** (tested on several machines):

```
!q::Send ^{F12}
```

---

*Update*

After **much** effort, I did get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to turn on the Chinese input mode with the following code, not sure why:

```
!q::Send ^{F6}
^F6::Send ^{F7}
^F7::Send ^{F12}
```

*But* because I also need to trigger a VSCode command using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> at the same time, I had to modify the above code to the following:

```
~!q::Send ^{F6} ; with ~ prefixed
^F6::Send ^{F7}
^F7::Send ^{F12}
```

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does trigger the VSCode command, but it won't turn on the Chinese input mode...

At last, if I take a step back and bind the VSCode command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (which could turn on the Chinese input mode with just `^c::Send ^{F12}`), I still have to prefix `^c` with `~`, otherwise it won't trigger the VSCode command, now I'm repeating the cycle all over again...

After all of these attempts, I have to say Sogou IME's logic for determining whether to enable the Chinese input mode is quite indeterminate, making the script for enabling the Chinese input mode very unreliable.

**In conclusion, even if I do all kinds of hacks and get the script working as intended, it's likely to break in the future, which is really not worth the trouble.**

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this and there's probably a more concise way to do it, but I think something like this should work.

```
!Q::
If(keyPressed = 1){
   ...Do a thing...
}
keyPressed := 1
SetTimer, altQTimer, 50
return

altQTimer:
keyPressed := 0
return
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me, I realized the key case sensitivity might matter? I've updated my question from `Q` to `q`. For easier debugging, could you please tell me how to trigger a command on just `Alt`+`q`? And better yet, being case-insensitive?

Comment: "!" means alt, so basically anything you put after "!Q::" will be triggered when you hit ALT+Q. and that subroutine will stop when it hits return. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

The timer might be too fast too idk, the 50 means 50 milliseconds

Comment: Thanks, I did some testings and found the keys are case-insensitive by default, but `Q::Send ^{F12}` works for me when pressing `Q`, while `!Q::Send ^{F12}` doesn't when pressing `Alt`+`Q`, do you know why?

Comment: Very weird, I don't know why. I just tested and it does work for me. I also tested my code above for the double click and it worked too, although 50 was way too fast. 200-250 is more reasonable. 

The docs have the following note on using ALT: 
`Pressing a hotkey which includes Alt may result in extra simulated keystrokes (Ctrl by default). See #MenuMaskKey.` I'm guessing maybe it actually does CTRL+ALT instead? not sure if that's helpful or not.

Comment: `!Q::SendInput foo` will insert `foo`, but `!Q::Send ^{F12}` does nothing, very strange, nonetheless, I'll upvote your answer.